# How to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for all URL.? I want to read epub from other server

Tags: laravel-5

I have develop one web site in Laravel 5, And I want read eBook using it's epub.
I have implement in local and put epub in local folder then it's work fine.
But This site Uploaded on QA server for test and actually epub comes from other server. 
If epub is upload on same hosting then working fine, But not read from other hosting.

Please help if any Idea.

I thing issue is  : 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header But I don't know how can solve.

Comment: It is highly because the other site is secured with https

Comment: No , It is not secured with https.